# Normal Matrix: Norm vs. Spectral Radius

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Define the following matrix norm:
$$
||A||=\frac{\max|\langle Ax,x\rangle|}{||x||_2^2}
$$
The spectral radius of $A$ is:
$$
\rho(A)=\max_i\{|\lambda_i|:Ax_i=\lambda_ix_i; x_i \neq 0\}
$$
Can you provide me some hints to show that:
$$
||A||=\rho(A) \text{ when } AA^T=A^TA?
$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052614/the-spectral-radius-of-normal-operator

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is normal, the spectral theorem applies. Now what happens if you write an arbitrary vector in terms of the eigenvector basis guaranteed by the spectral theorem?