# Spectrum of T is singleton and and T is normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

The following question was asked in my assignment of spectral theory and I am not able to make much progress on it.

> Question: Let H be a complex Hilbert Space and let $T\in L(H)$ be normal. If $\sigma(T)$ is singleton {$\lambda$} , then show that $T=\lambda I$.

I am sorry but I am not able to make any progress on how to proceed towards proving  this statement. I have been following my class notes.

Can you please give a couple of hints?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\sigma(T-\lambda I) $ ? The operator $T-\lambda I$ is normal as well. Perhaps you have a formula in your notes relating the spectral radius of a normal operator and its norm. Apply that to $T-\lambda I.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the spectral mapping theorem, if $T$ is a normal operator and $f:\sigma(T)\to\mathbb C$ a continuous function, then $\sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))$. Letting $f(x) = x-\lambda$, we see that $\sigma(T-\lambda I)=0$, and $T-\lambda I$ is normal as well.

Recall that  [the spectral radius of a normal operator is equal to its operator norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052614/the-spectral-radius-of-normal-operator), which immediately implies that $T-\lambda I=0$, or $T=\lambda I$.

Comment: If you  have some time to spare , then please help me with this also? I shall be grateful.